# Loader works only on the first ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want the loader to stay until the complete execution is complete and statement $("#xyzDiv").html(data) has been executed. Currently the loader gets hidden after the first ajax call. Even if i add "beforeSend: function () { $("#loader").show(); }" to GetDataList(), the loader is not staying.

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxUrl,
    data: dataObj,
    beforeSend: function () { $("#loader").show(); },
    success: function (data)
    {
        if (data.result)
        {
            GetDataList();
            toastr.success(data.strMsg);
        }
        else
        {
            toastr.error(data.strMsg);
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus)
    {
         var msg = HandleAjaxErrorMessage(jqXHR, textStatus);
        console.log(msg);
        toastr.error('An error occurred. Please try again');
    },
    complete: function () { $("#loader").hide(); }
});

function GetDataList()
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "Get",
        url: ajaxUrl,
        data: dataObj,
        success: function (data)
        {
            $("#xyzDiv").html(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) 
        {
            var msg = HandleAjaxErrorMessage(jqXHR, textStatus);
            console.log(msg);
            toastr.error('An error occurred. Please try again');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Place `$("#loader").hide();` in your success/error of `GetDataList` and in your `error` of your first `ajax` call. Remove `complete` from first `ajax` call

Comment: It looks like `GetDataList` is also an async function and you are not doing anything with the promise that `$.ajax` returns in the caller.  Without waiting on `GetDataList`, the `complete` method will run without caring about `GetDataList`'s status.  It seems like you need get the promise back from `GetDataList` and only when it's `success` method is called do you hide the loader.